# Add multiple lines in title bar

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have some situation here. I need to have multiple lines in title bar in window in the .net.One line must be dynamic.How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

To draw to the non-client area of a window, you're going to need to implement a custom window chrome, which can be quite a bit of work, requiring native Win32 calls.

Here's a [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2008/09/08/custom-window-chrome-in-wpf.aspx) to help you get started if you want to do it yourself. Or, an existing [library](http://wpfwindow.codeplex.com/) at CodePlex, which may be sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks. Exact answer Im looking for is codeplex library..Thanks very Much